# intellij popup javadoc on mouse hover on file name

Tags: intellij-idea, hover, mouse, javadoc

I was hoping there is a way to enable this feature where when I hover the mouse over a class under Project Explorer, contents of the javadoc will popup like it does inside the code editor.

[image]

Has anyone been able to figure this out?

Comment: Feel free to create feature request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA